# Generate 'ecdf' on a grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

How to store an ecdf output from a grouped data frame

Hi all,

My data looks like this:

```
age lab  value  
20  wbc  7.0   
20  wbc  6.5
20  rbc  3.5
30  rbc  4.0
30  plt  100
30  plt  120
40  wbc  5.0
40  wbc  7.5
40  rbc  4.1
... ...  ...
```

I would like to generate and store ecdf's for the variable "value" for all the possible "age"-"lab" combinations. The output should be a list of "ecdf" objects. I plan to use these ecdf's at a later point in my analysis and apply it to another dataset.

What I tried so far:

```
data %>% group_by(age,lab) %>% do(ecdf(.$value))
```

No success so far. I am getting:

```
Error: Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... must be data frames, not ecdf/stepfun/function
```

Any thoughts?

SOLVED

If this helps anyone, I split the original data-frame by two factors, then used an lapply on the third column.

```
spl <- split(data, list(data$age, data$lab))
ecdfs <- lapply(spl, function(x) ecdf(x$value)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(age, lab) %>%
  do(data.frame(., newval = ecdf(.$value)(.$value)))
```

---

Or with `mutate`

```
data %>% 
   group_by(age, lab) %>% 
   mutate(newval = ecdf(value)(value))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   age, lab [6]
#    age lab   value newval
#  <int> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    20 wbc     7      1  
#2    20 wbc     6.5    0.5
#3    20 rbc     3.5    1  
#4    30 rbc     4      1  
#5    30 plt   100      0.5
#6    30 plt   120      1  
#7    40 wbc     5      0.5
#8    40 wbc     7.5    1  
#9    40 rbc     4.1    1
```

#### Update

If we want to store the function as a column, then wrap it in a `list`

```
data %>% 
    group_by(age, lab) %>% 
    mutate(ecdfFun = list(ecdf(value)))
```

It can also be `summarise`d

```
data %>%
   group_by(age, lab) %>%
   summarise(ecdfFun = list(ecdf(value)))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(age = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 
 40L), lab = c("wbc", "wbc", "rbc", "rbc", "plt", "plt", "wbc", 
 "wbc", "rbc"), value = c(7, 6.5, 3.5, 4, 100, 120, 5, 7.5, 4.1
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply but I do not wish to calculate the quantiles of the existing data. My desired output is the "ecdf" itself (class = "ecdf"), which I plan to apply later on another dataset.

Comment: @JohnCena  Then, store it in a `list` as in the update